# Clicking Accept cookies button using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate some download of data and have an issue with accepting the cookies message.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from random import randint
import time

current_link = "https://platform.smapone.com/Portal/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FPortal%2F"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(current_link)
#driver.switch_to.frame("cookieConsentIframe")
#driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('cookieConsentIframe'))

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='cookieConsentIframe']")))
    print(1)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@id="cookies-accept-all"]').click()
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[text()="Accept"]').click()
except:
    pass
 
time.sleep(randint(5,8))   
driver.quit()
```

The code runs through (prints also the 1) but never clicks the button. Any suggestions? Tried so many things already.

Answer (score 2):

You need to also wait out the button:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="cookies-accept-all"]'))).click()
```

EDIT Here is a full example (selenium/chromedriver setup is for linux, but you need to observe only the imports, and part after defining the browser):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)



url = 'https://platform.smapone.com/Portal/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FPortal%2F'
browser.get(url)

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='cookieConsentIframe']")))
    
## sortout cookie button
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@id="cookies-accept-all"]'))).click()
    print("accepted cookies")
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button')
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied it exactly? because it works.... I'll post  out a full example

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, forgot click() :) Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The element <kbd>Accept</kbd> is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://platform.smapone.com/Portal/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FPortal%2F'})
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.cookieConsent#cookieConsentIframe")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#cookies-accept-all span.btn-accept"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://platform.smapone.com/Portal/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FPortal%2F'})
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='cookieConsent' and @id='cookieConsentIframe']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='cookies-accept-all']//span[@class='btn-accept']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: smapone]